# Является ли код примером инкапсуляции?

Tags: php, ооп, инкапсуляция

Суть в том, что при импользовании метода `getDesignId()` само существование метода `getDesignVersion()` скрыто от нас, мы не знаем о нём, т.е. он инкапсулирован?

```
class Design extends DB
{
  private $obj = 'объект';

  public function getDesignVersion()
  {
    $data = $obj->get($this->site_id);
    return $data["design_version"];
  }

  public function getDesignId()
  {
    $data = $this->get($this->getDesignVersion());
    return $data["design_id"];
  }
}
```

Comment: вот если вы сделаете метод getDesignVersion приватным, он точно будет инкапсулирован, но в целом код можно назвать примером инкапсуляции по отношению к $obj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет. Т.к. он объявлен с модификатором `public` и его существование не скрыто от внешней программы. Данный метод может быть вызван автономно вне метода `getDesignId`